# Conditional probability of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable whose pdf is $cx^3$ (for some constant $c$) in the range  $0 \le x \le 1$, and is $0$ outside this range.

- Find $\rm{Pr}(1/3 \le X \le 2/3 \;|\; X \le 1/2)$

Comment: Isn't this just Pr1$[1/3 \leq 1/2]?

Comment: I've formatted your post using latex / markdown. However I wasn't clear what you meant by "and is 0 outside this range", so I left that bit. Maybe you can clarify / edit your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event $\frac{1}{3}\le X\le \frac{2}{3}$ and let $B$ be the event $X\le \frac{1}{2}$. We want $\Pr(A|B)$.

Recall that in general $\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

The event $A\cap B$ is the event $\frac{1}{3}\le X\le \frac{1}{2}$.

Now compute. We have 
$$\Pr(A\cap B)=\int_{1/3}^{1/2}cx^3 \,dx=\frac{c}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2^4}-\frac{1}{3^4}\right).$$
Similarly,
$$\Pr(B)=\frac{c}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2^4}.$$
Divide. Note that the $c$'s cancel, so we do not need to compute $c$, though we easily could. Maybe simplify a bit. We get
$$1-\frac{2^4}{3^4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=cx^{3}$ be the pdf of x. Since f is a pdf, $\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=1$. This will imply that $c=4$. Now since you want $P(1/3 \leq X \leq 2/3 | x \leq 1/2)$, you only need to evaluate $\int\limits_{1/3}^{1/2}f(x)dx$ .

Comment: "you only need to"... No, the computation you suggest will not give $P(X\le1/2)$, which is also needed. @Upvoter: Why the upvote?